# Pre-Trained Models in Keras,TorchVision

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I Have The Following Code which use pre-trained `ResNet50` Model in Keras with `imagenet` DataSet:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
print(model)
```

and it works fine..My question is can i find a pre-trained model inside Keras or Torchvision or TensorFlow But to one of the following:

```
1) LeNet5 for MNIST DataSet
2) 32-Layer ResNet for the CIFAR-10 Dataset
```

I know the alternative is to train the LeNet5 for example on my own, but a pre-trained model will be preferred and as far as I searched I didn't find them.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also been exploring Tensorflow's pretrained model landscape and (as of 1/14/2020), solutions don't exist for 1) a mnist-pretrained lenet or 2) a cifar10-pretrained 32-layer resnet.

Honestly, I strongly doubt that most frameworks release a pretrained model for LeNet-5. It's extremely small and usually takes O(minutes) to train.

Aside from the [`tf.keras.applications`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html) module you mentioned, some other potential options are:

- The [official `tensorflow/models` repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models), which contains model examples for [mnist](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/mnist_main.py) and a [32-layer resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/resnet_cifar_model.py)
- Swithing to `pytorch`, which has [various models](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html) pretrained on imagenet

I realize neither of these are ideal.